# Banana Disease Plants' Leaves Images/Datasets

Tags: image, image-processing

Where can I find images/datasets of healthy and diseased banana plants' leaves? I tried to look from the plantvillage.org but their image database was not found. Please help me guys, I will use it for disease detection using image processing.

Comment: Find the biggest exporters of bananas http://www.freshplaza.com/article/2824/The-worlds-biggest-banana-exporting-countries and ask their International Trade departments maybe.

Answer (score 1):

**check this link**
https://github.com/godliver/source-code-BBW-BBS/

it contains images of banana infected by bacterial wilt, banana black segatoka, and healthy leaf images